# Php switch choose only couple of letters from alphabet

Tags: php

I wanted so it could print only variables i set but its printing everything from here
when i use break its printing only for A

```
<?php
$A=1;
$B=2;
$E=5;

switch($A OR $B OR $E)
{
    case 1:
    {
        printf("Letter A is first in alphabet <br>");
    }
    case 2:
    {
        printf("Letter B is second in alphabet <br>");
    }
    case 3:
    {
        printf("Letter C is third in alphabet <br>");
    }
    case 4:
    {
        printf("Letter D is fourth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    case 5:
    {
        printf("Letter E is fifth in alphabet <br>");
    }
}
?>
```

I tried using array i don't know if i had set it right i used

```
<?php
$A= array(
    "A" => 1,
    "B" => 2,
    "E" => 5,
    );
switch($A)
{
    case 1:
    {
        printf("Letter A is first in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        printf("Letter B is second in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        printf("Letter C is third in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        printf("Letter D is fourth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 5:
    {
        printf("Letter E is fifth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

But nothing appears
then i tried using in array just numbers

```
<?php
$A=array(1,2,5);
switch($A)
{
    case 1:
    {
        printf("Letter A is first in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        printf("Letter B is second in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        printf("Letter C is third in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        printf("Letter D is fourth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 5:
    {
        printf("Letter E is fifth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

I dont know if im using array properly im new with it so if i could get some advice ty in advance.
I need this for school and most of my friends and me are freaking about it i hope this helps you to help me resolve my problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, but you should probably read a manual: https://php.net/switch

Comment: `$A OR $F OR $J` will only grab/see the first variable; nothing after that. You need to rethink this. Using an array is one option.

Comment: Well how can i explain lets say
i set variables 
example:
$A=1
$B=2
$C=3
and i want to use switch so it could print me only those letters
In case i typed every letter from A to Z and i want it to print only couple of those like those i set variables for

Comment: Seeing the edit. You need to place `break;` after each case. This aside from the comment I left about `OR`'s.

Comment: Set your array with some values.  Then loop in that array (`foreach`) and apply the switch on each element, one by one.  Or go more "advanced" and use `array_walk`.  The way you coded it, it will not apply the switch to each array element.

Answer (score 1):

> please try this, i hope this what you want.

```php
<?php
$A = array(1,2,5);
foreach ($A as $no){
    switch($no){
        case 1:
            printf("Letter A is first in alphabet <br>");
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("Letter B is second in alphabet <br>");
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("Letter C is third in alphabet <br>");
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("Letter D is fourth in alphabet <br>");
        break;
        case 5:
            printf("Letter E is fifth in alphabet <br>");
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Maybe you are having a misconception in switch cases in PHP. You need to pass the single value in the variable in the switch(). It is important to understand how the switch statement is executed in order to avoid mistakes. The switch statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed. Only when a case statement is found whose expression evaluates to a value that matches the value of the switch expression does PHP begin to execute the statements. PHP continues to execute the statements until the end of the switch block, or the first time it sees a break statement. If you don't write a break statement at the end of a case's statement list, PHP will go on executing the statements

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
//$A = 1;
//$A = 2;
//$A = 3;
//$A = 4;
$A = 5;
//$A=7;
switch($A)
{
    case 1:
    {
        printf("Letter A is first in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        printf("Letter B is second in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 3:
    {
        printf("Letter C is third in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 4:
    {
        printf("Letter D is fourth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    case 5:
    {
        printf("Letter E is fifth in alphabet <br>");
    }
    break;
    default:
        printf("No alphabet  assigned <br>");
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```